# On the regularity of any reparametrezation of a regular curve

Tags: differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, curves, parametrization

According to *Differential Geometry* by Pressley:

> $\mathsf{Proposition}\:\mathsf{1.3}$
>
> *Any reparametrisation of a regular curve is regular.*
>
>
>
> *Proof* $\it{1.3}$
>
> Suppose that $\gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}$ are related as in Definition 1.5, let $t=\phi(\tilde{t})$, and let $\psi=\phi^{-1}$ so that $\tilde{t}=\psi(t)$. Differentiating both sides of the equation $\phi(\psi(t))=t$ with respect to $t$ and using the chain rule gives $${{\raise{0.3pt}{d\phi}}\above{0.5pt}{d\tilde{t}}} \frac{d\psi}{\lower{1pt}{dt}}=1.$$ This shows that $d\phi/d\tilde{t}$ is never zero. Since $\tilde{\gamma}(\tilde{t})=\gamma(\phi(\tilde{t}))$, another application of the chain rule gives $${{\raise{0.3pt}{d\tilde{\gamma}}}\above{0.5pt}{d\tilde{t}}}=\frac{d\gamma}{\lower{1pt}{dt}}{{\raise{0.3pt}{d\phi}}\above{0.5pt}{d\tilde{t}}},$$ which shows that $d\tilde{\gamma}/d\tilde{t}$ is never zero if $d\gamma/dt$ is never zero. $\hspace{6.2cm}\square$

Now suppose the parabola $y=x^2$ and the parametrazation $\gamma(t) = (t, t^2)$ and also reparametrazation $\delta(t)=(t^3, t^6)$. Obviously the function $\phi(t)=t^3$ is strictly monotone and continuously differentiable. Nonetheless, $\gamma(t)$ is regular but $\delta(t)$ is not! What did I do wrong? Or is the proof incorrect?

Maybe the following definition from the same book is wrong; that is, it must include that $d\phi/dt $ is never zero in all its domain?

> $\mathsf{Definition}\:\mathsf{1.5}$
>
> A parametrised curve $\tilde{\gamma}:(\tilde{\alpha},\tilde{\beta})\to\mathbf{R}^n$ is a *reparametrisation* of a parametrised curve $\gamma:(\alpha,\beta)\to\mathbf{R}^n$ if there is a smooth bijective map $\phi:(\tilde{\alpha},\tilde{\beta})\to(\alpha,\beta)$ (the *reparametrisation map*) such that the inverse map $\phi^{-1}:(\alpha,\beta)\to(\tilde{\alpha},\tilde{\beta})$ is also smooth and $$\tilde{\gamma}(\tilde{t})=\gamma(\phi(\tilde{t}))\:\:\text{for all}\:\:\tilde{t}\in(\tilde{\alpha},\tilde{\beta}).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism (a smooth bijection with a smooth inverse) then $\frac{d\phi}{dt} \ne 0$.

This is because $\phi \circ \phi^{-1} = \text{id}$ so $$1 = \frac{d(\text{id})}{dt} = d(\phi^{-1} \circ \phi) = \frac{d\phi^{-1}}{d\phi} \frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

In particular we see that $\frac{d\phi}{dt} \ne 0$.

Comment: Am I right to say that 1) if derivative of a contentiously differentiable function is nonzero at some point its inverse exists at that point and it is contentiously differentiable for some interval about that point? 2) The converse of the (1) holds?

Comment: @Edi Yes, the first statement is a consequence of the inverse mapping theorem. The converse is also true: if $\phi$ is a smooth bijection around $t_0$ with smooth inverse then $\dot\phi(t_0) \ne 0$, as the above discussion shows.

Answer (score 0):

See definition 1.3.1 in Pressley's textbook:

[image]

For him, a reparametrization is a smooth bijective map whose inverse is also smooth. That does not occur with $t\mapsto t^3$.

Comment: there is no "definition 1.3.1" in the book (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781848828902)! But the same definition the Pressley gives and I don't understand why $t\mapsto t^3$ is not bijective or smooth

Comment: @Edi Yes, there is. I have it before my eyes. And $t\mapsto\sqrt[3]t$ is not smooth.

Comment: Haha it's Def. 1.5 in the edition that I am reading (same definition)!

Comment: Following the comment below @mechanodroid's answer, I think the inverse of of $t\mapsto t^3$ is not smooth because d/dt (t^3) is not never-zero?

Comment: @Edi Yes, that would be correct.